# Calling a function in lua passing a parameter

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have the following function

**DOESN'T WORK:**

```
local function onPlayBtnRelease(level)
    storyboard.gotoScene( level, "fade", 500 )
    return true 
end
```

I want to pass a parameter so the appropriate level to be loaded, so I have the following button:

```
planet1 = widget.newButton{
    label="1",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        fontSize=25,
        defaultFile="levelplanet.png",
        overFile="levelplanet-over.png",
        width=62, height=62,
        onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease("loadscene1")  -- event listener function
    }
```

but the above doesn't work.

**THAT IS OK:**

If I do

```
local function onPlayBtnRelease
    storyboard.gotoScene( "loadscene1", "fade", 500 )
    return true 
end


planet1 = widget.newButton{
        label="1",
            labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
            fontSize=25,
            defaultFile="levelplanet.png",
            overFile="levelplanet-over.png",
            width=62, height=62,
            onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease    
        }
```

It compiles. How can I pass a parameter to `onPlayBtnRelease` ? Any idea why this causes a compilation error?

**The error:**

```
Runtime error
bad argument #1 to 'find' (string expected, got table)
stack traceback:
        [C]: ?
        [C]: in function 'error'
        ?: in function 'gotoScene'
```

Comment: Could You show us that exact compilation error please? And which Widget library version are You using?

Comment: @Kamiccolo I updated the post putting the exact error message.

Comment: Replace `onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease("loadscene1")  -- event listener function` with `onRelease = function() onPlayBtnRelease("loadscene1") end`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff that works until the call of the `storyboard.gotoScene( level, "fade", 500 )` then a string expected but `level` is a table. any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation of this line:

```
onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease("loadscene1")  -- event listener function
```

This line calls `onPlayBtnRelease("loadscene1")` and assigns the return value to the field `onRelease`. So, what you probably need is to do it like this:

```
onRelease = function() return onPlayBtnRelease("loadscene1") end
```

If you need to do this a lot, you can make a closure generator like this

```
local function newclosure(func, ...)
    local args = {...}
    return function()
        return func(unpack(args));
    end
end
```

This way you only have to write the line like this:

```
onRelease = newclosure(onPlayBtnRelease, "loadscene1")
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is most probably caused by:

```
local function onPlayBtnRelease
    storyboard.gotoScene( "loadscene1", "fade", 500 )
    return true 
end
```

because of the missing parameter list in the function definition.

The error could be similar to this, I guess:

```
G:\root\main\core\Lua/app/lua51/bin/lua.exe: lua_08.lua:5: 
 '(' expected near 'storyboard'
```

From what you posted it seems that `onPlayBtnRelease` is an [event listener](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/type/Listener.html) function, thus it should be declared as a function taking a single parameter which is the triggered event:

```
local function onPlayBtnRelease(event)
    // ... code ...
    return true 
end
```

**EDIT**

The `onRelease` field must be the listener, not the result it returns when it is called. Try simply this:

```
planet1 = widget.newButton{
    label="1",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        fontSize=25,
        defaultFile="levelplanet.png",
        overFile="levelplanet-over.png",
        width=62, height=62,
        onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease
    }
```

Comment: but in the first case, where the error exists, I have parameter list in the function definition

Comment: I know that this works but what I want to achieve is to have one function for all  the levels `onPlayBtnRelease` and inside the `onPlayBtnRelease` use if statements to choose which level to load based on the parameter in the function definition. Is that possible?

Comment: @AvraamMavridis You have no control on the parameter being passed to that listener, since it is called by the "event loop". The listener is passed that single parameter which is the event that was fired. To find an alternative, you must tell us where you store the information on which is the current level. Is it in a global? Is it in a local which is visible from the listener *definition*?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is possible to associate needable data outside of the constructor? For example:

```
planet1 = widget.newButton { -- then initialize as usuall
 }
planet1.next_scene = "loadscene1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Wondering, if You can build Widget object with some non-standart options without wrapping it into another table like this:

```
local function onPlayBtnRelease(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene(event.target.next_scene, "fade", 500 )
    return true 
end


planet1 = widget.newButton{
        label="1",
        labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
        fontSize=25,
        defaultFile="levelplanet.png",
        overFile="levelplanet-over.png",
        width=62, height=62,
        next_scene = "loadscene1"
}
```

If it won't work, table listeners are the ones You're looking for.

Comment: what about `planet1.next_scene = "loadscene1"`?
meh... still want to avoid wrapping... :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will work for certain.

```
local onPlayBtnRelease = function(event)
    storyboard.gotoScene(event.target.myScene, "fade", 500 )
    return true 
end


planet1 = widget.newButton{
    label="1",
    labelColor = { default={255}, over={128} },
    fontSize=25,
    defaultFile="levelplanet.png",
    overFile="levelplanet-over.png",
    width=62, height=62,
    onRelease = onPlayBtnRelease
}
planet1.myScene = "yourSceneName"
```